# View subpackages/directories in the project NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, view, project, subdirectory

Bad(now):

- *.b
- *.b.c
- *.b.d

Good(intention):

- *.b

  - c
  - d

Bad:

[image: bad]

Good:

[image: good]

How do I set such a view in NetBeans 8.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on empty space of Project Explorer panel
2. Choose View Java Packages As > Tree option to change the view

To get some graphical explanation please visit this link http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2011/06/hierarchy-view-in-project-panel-of.html